# Is possible to compare key that use installed app with key of new version this app

Tags: android, android-keystore

I've reinstalled windows and accidentally removed the key-store file that I've used for my project. I try to make a new one, but something is not inserted like the last time(alias maybe.) Now I have a problem: When I start to update the.apk file I get the following message:

`An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed.`

My application automatically checks for project updates (new version) on a private server. The problem is that some people already have an app on their phone.

My idea was to compare keys and if it's different to ask the user to remove old apps in some dialog or something like that.

Is something like this possible, if not what are my others options ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to release a new app with a new packagename.

If you no longer have the keystore used to sign your first app, you can never update it again in Play Store.

If you distributed your app manually and have not released it  via Play Store, your users can uninstall the app signed with the lost key and install the new one.

There is no way to show a dialog as you cannot update the app. You can only replace it as described above.